# How to resolve a NULL cString crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, encoding, cstring

I'm getting a crash with the following encoding fix I'm trying to implement:

```
  // encoding fix
    NSString *correctStringTitle = [NSString stringWithCString:[[item objectForKey:@"main_tag"] cStringUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    cell.titleLabel.text = [correctStringTitle capitalizedString];
```

my crash log output states:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** +[NSString stringWithCString:encoding:]: NULL cString'
```

thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to think that a double conversion is necessary in order to get the correct result. It isn't, nor is it possible (that's why the call to `cStringUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding` returns `NULL`). Just leave this part out and assign to `correctStringTitle` directly.

Comment: I trimmed it down to:     // encoding fix
    cell.titleLabel.text = [[NSString stringWithCString:[[item objectForKey:@"main_tag"] cStringUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding]]capitalizedString]; but the encoding issue remains. are you saying to remove the cStringUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding completely? thanks

Comment: I thought I had to use this Latin1StringEncoding for some Spanish accented characters that were displaying. it should look like this then: cell.titleLabel.text = [[NSString stringWithCString:[[item objectForKey:@"main_tag"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]   capitalizedString];  ?

Comment: @hanumanDev 1. Why would you **have to?** The encoding is your choice. 2. No, remove all that clutter. `cell.titleLabel.text = [[item objectForKey:@"main_tag"];`.

Comment: the problem is that if I don't encode then some character show up like "Espaå+_A" etc... particularly with Spanish

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with italian accented characters while trying to get text from html and my solution to avoid the situation that `cStringUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding` returns `NULL` is ensuring that when you get the html from data you use:

```
[[NSString alloc] initWithData:self.responseData encoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding]
```

and not

```
encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
```